# how to estimate the TCO of open source implementations

Tags: open-source, sakai

I mean, this is [Sakai](http://sakaiproject.org/portal), the open source project of a learning management system. But, really I'm clueless trying to estimate the hidden costs in one implementation project (on the technology side, not the pedagogy-stuff) in a small-medium scale institution.

- Deployment (1 engineer two or three months, with experience in Java EE)
- Customisation (1 engineer, 1 designer two or three months also)
- Support (1 guy)
- One server reasonably good with 4, 8 or 16 GB in RAM. It will host the application server, the database server, and da da! ?
- ???

can somebody experienced, give me advice in how to estimate the TCO in open source implementations like this? In fact, it could be Moodle, and in that case I would be lost too!

Yep, is not really a question of programming, but I think that this is one proper place to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined [in the help center](/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on support staff for a large uni that uses Blackboard. All the support people are students working part time, so salary can be pretty low per hour. You'll want to have someone on permanent staff as an administrator, who could also be the developer/deployment guy. Perhaps only part time if your institution is small enough, but someone who knows the ins and outs of the system will be handy *when* (not if) things go wrong. (Maybe you could combine them with the support role?)  On that note, you'll probably want a seperate server for backups and recovery, at the least something that will backup data.

If your school is small enough, maybe one person could handle the admin/support/dev roles by themselves (my roles are both support and developent and I often wish I had admin priveleges). You could probably talk to your IT department on how much servers are going for these days, I'm not sure there or on competitive salary ranges (but students are cheap.) Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 1):

[Sakai Deployments](http://jira.sakaiproject.org/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&&pid=10280&sorter/field=issuekey&sorter/order=ASC) lists details of some Sakai deployments, but be careful to check the last updated date as I would look a deployment data that has been updated in the last year.

Comment: Good tip abut the deployments page. But they don't get updated regularly, especially if things aren't changing much in the deployments. The data is more of a representative view than an exact view of peoples installations.

Answer (score 1):

I manage a Sakai deployment and all aspects are doable with one FTE, which includes full customisation and development. For larger installations (>10K users) and for more customisation, consider adding another FTE.